# Automate update REST API Client during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, swagger

My company is looking to implement applications using Azure API Apps. Client applications will create REST API clients using Swagger documents located in the Azure portal. Any changes to the Azure API apps will cause an update to the Swagger document when the service is published.

Is there a way to automate the download of the service's swagger document so that the REST API client can be rebuilt/updated during the build process (e.g. something like a pre-build step)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which tool do you use for the client generation now?

Comment: Right now it's a manual process: using Visual Studio 2015, right-click the project, select Add -> REST API Client, and then manually specify the Swagger document url.

Comment: If you've the URL to the swagger document, You may consider using [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators) to generate REST API clients (e.g. C#, Ruby, ObjC, Swift, Typescript, etc) online.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio's `Add / Rest Api Client...` option is using the [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) library for the code generation. You can download this tool as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/autorest/) and use the `AutoRest.exe` command line tool to generate the output.

For example:

```
AutoRest.exe -CodeGenerator CSharp -Modeler Swagger -Input https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-simple.json -Namespace MyNamespace
```

**Another way** is to use the [Swagger codegen library](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). This is a java based command line tool, which can generate some C# code too.

Comment: I'll certainly look into this. Thank you for the info, @Tóth Tibor.

Comment: Coninued: This worked, at least to some degree. Using this method resulted in some unresolved references (e.g. NewtonSoft.Json methods). The original method resolves everything just fine.

I'll keep at this and see if there's more that can be done.